# Calling JavaScript function before and after ajax request in yii ajaxSubmitButton

Tags: php, jquery, yii

How can I add a JavaScript function before and after the AJAX call?

This my Yii Code:

```
echo CHtml::ajaxSubmitButton('Create Invoice',$this->createUrl('url'),
array(
   'type'=>'POST',
   'data'=> 'js:{"merchant_id": $("#merchantSearchForm_merchant_list").val() }',
   'success'=>'js:function(string){ $("#merchantProfileForm").html(string); }'
),array('class'=>'someCssClass',));
```

I need to call a JavaScript function when the user clicks on button, and when the request returns the response, I need to call another JavaScript function.

The workflow would be:

1. User clicks on button
2. Call `loader();` function
3. AJAX request and return the response
4. Call `hidLoder();` function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Already you are calling some js function after ajax response (in success)

For before ajax call option: you can set another option in ajaxSubmitButton

```
 'beforeSend'=>'js:function(data){
        }',
```